# Mapping Data from multiple table

Tags: database, ms-access

I built this union query to merge the code field to find which code is found in which table.

```
SQL=SELECT GOLD.code,1 AS Tbl1,0 AS Tbl2
FROM GOLD LEFT JOIN ADN ON GOLD.code = ADN.code
UNION
SELECT GOLD.code,0 AS Tbl1,1 AS Tbl2
FROM GOLD RIGHT JOIN ADN ON GOLD.code = ADN.code;
```

Here the results

```
Code          Tbl1 Tbl2
030?1975*007    0   1
030?1975*008    1   0
030 2259)000    1   0
Y031-1046-002x  1   0
031-1302-000    1   0
031-1303-000    1   0
031-1308-000    1   0
031-71013-RFX   1   0
04-035t:10-002  0   1
04-035t:10-003  1   0
04-035410-000   0   1
04-035410-000   1   0
04-035410-003   0   1
04-035410-003   1   0
047kjlkj**re    1   0
48              1   0
```

But I would like to get more compact like this where there is no duplicate because I will manipulate more that 500000 records par tables.

```
Code          Tbl1 Tbl2
030?1975*007    0   1
030?1975*008    1   0
030 2259)000    1   0
Y031-1046-002x  1   0
031-1302-000    1   0
031-1303-000    1   0
031-1308-000    1   0
031-71013-RFX   1   0
04-035t:10-002  0   1
04-035t:10-003  1   0
04-035410-000   1   1
04-035410-003   1   1
047kjlkj**re    1   0
48              1   0
```

or like that where tbl1 and tbl2 are merged into the mapping fields. This willbe the best.

```
Code         Mapping
030?1975*007    01
030?1975*008    10
030 2259)000    10
Y031-1046-002x  10
031-1302-000    10
031-1303-000    10
031-1308-000    10
031-71013-RFX   10
04-035t:10-002  01
04-035t:10-003  10
04-035410-000   11
04-035410-003   11
047kjlkj**re    10
48              10
```

Here the 2 tables

```
GOLD
Code
030?1975*008
030 2259)000
Y031-1046-002x
031-1302-000
031-1303-000
031-1308-000
031-71013-RFX
04-035t:10-003
04-035410-000
04-035410-003
047kjlkj**re
```

and

```
ADN
Code
030?1975*007
04-035t:10-002
04-035410-000
04-035410-003
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to wrap your query in a select getting only max from t1,t2 group by code..  This would be easier if access supported a full outer join.

```
SQL=
SELECT code, max(tbl1) as tbl1, max(tbl2) as tbl2, max(tbl1)&''&Max(tbl2) as stringversion
FROM (
SELECT GOLD.code,1 AS Tbl1,0 AS Tbl2 
FROM GOLD 
LEFT JOIN ADN 
  ON GOLD.code = ADN.code 
UNION 
SELECT GOLD.code,0 AS Tbl1,1 AS Tbl2 
FROM GOLD 
RIGHT JOIN ADN 
  ON GOLD.code = ADN.code) A
GROUP BY Code;
```

stringversion should combine the max of two columns together if that is the preferred output.  I'm relying on some implicit casting though. by adding '' a string to a what appears to be a numeric datatype

This is commonly done in access by building a new query based on our existing one that simply aggregates the data.

Comment: Thanks it does work  with small correction                                  SELECT code, max(Tbl1) as tbl3, max(Tbl2) as tbl4, max(Tbl1)&''&Max(Tbl2) as stringversion
FROM (
SELECT GOLD.code,1 AS Tbl1,0 AS Tbl2 
FROM GOLD 
LEFT JOIN ADN 
  ON GOLD.code = ADN.code
UNION SELECT GOLD.code,0 AS Tbl1,1 AS Tbl2 
FROM GOLD 
RIGHT JOIN ADN 
  ON GOLD.code = ADN.code)
GROUP BY Code;